# Unable to access code after returned object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having some trouble authenticating with a factory in my app. The goal is to get a token only if the user has not already been authenticated. When I use the code below, I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'uid' of null

I can't tell if this is just a minor syntax issue or something bigger. It looks like none of the code starting with `var authData` is being read.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
   angular.module('firebase.auth', ['firebase', 'firebase.ref'])

   .factory('Auth', ['$firebaseAuth', 'Ref', function ($firebaseAuth, Ref) {

        return $firebaseAuth(Ref);
        var authData = Ref.getAuth();
        console.log(authData);

         if (authData) {
            console.log('already logged in with ' + authData.uid);
          } else {

            return Auth.$authAnonymously({rememberMe: true}).then(showError);

             function showError(err) {
              Login.err = err;
            }
          }
        }
    ]);
})();

angular.module('App')

   .factory('Projects', function ($firebaseArray, fbURL, Auth, Ref) {
        var authData = Ref.getAuth();
        var ref = new Firebase(fbURL + '/projects/' + authData.uid);
          return $firebaseArray(ref);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 return $firebaseAuth(Ref);
```

> It looks like none of the code starting with var authData is being read.

You stuck a return statement at the top of your function. That will exit the function.

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean I need to use a new factory for the code that starts with `var authData`, or is there a better way to accomplish my goal here?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure *what* your goal is here. Can you give a little background explanation of what `$firebaseAuth` is and why you might need to return it at the top like you are?

Comment: I'm using [Firebase](http://www.firebase.com) as my backend. [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html) is its AngularJS library. All of this is very new to me, but I think `$firebaseAuth` is a service and the returned object contains methods for authenticating users. I thought I needed to put it at the top in order to use `getAuth()` to retrieve the current authentication state (to determine whether the user has already been authenticated and authenticate anonymously, if need be). Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi Ken. A factory is supposed to create something and return it. In this case, you're creating the service. If you want to manipulate it in some way, then simply say `var myService = $firebaseAuth(Ref)` and use `myService` when you want to access `$firebaseAuth`. Make sure, at the bottom, you return `myService`.